# Karate - Possible to put scenario in a loop?

Tags: unit-testing, karate

I want to know if it's possible to put scenario in a loop?
Imagine I have a scenario that I want to test it 10 times with 10 different data in a list. It's a good Idea to put whole scenario in a loop and even set scenario name in the loop. Is it possible?

Comment: @PeterThomas OK peter, Thanks to you previous answers, I will check them soon, Is it possible to answer this question too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is what Karate's data-driven `call` does. You need to split code into a second feature file (with only one scenario).

Here is the link to the documentation: [Data Driven Features](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features).

And in the [karate demos](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo) look at the examples `call-json-array.feature` and `call-table.feature`.

Comment: Thomos, 'call-json-array.feature' is just awesome example. It made testers life simple from complex programming world .

Comment: @Anupama great ! make sure you read the docs on the new “dynamic scenario outline” also